# Why do Tradingview VWAP standard deviation values not match excel STDEV?

Tags: excel, pine-script

I've searched all over stack overflow - but couldnt figure it out:

**The Tradingview (TV) built-in indicator VWAP (anchored at session start) standard deviation (e.g. included in Upper Band) does not match the standard deviation I get from Excel (STDEV()) using the same VWAP data:  **

| VWAP | STDEV Excel | STDEV TV | Upper Band value TV | Upper Band Excel | Delta (expect 0) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3905.50 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 3905.50 | 3905.50 | 0 |
| 3905.29 | 0.15 | 0.34 | 3905.63 | 3905.44 | 0.19 |
| 3905.26 | 0.13 | 0.33 | 3905.60 | 3905.39 | 0.20 |
| 3905.35 | 0.11 | 0.42 | 3905.76 | 3905.45 | 0.31 |
| 3905.37 | 0.09 | 0.44. | 3905.81 | 3905.47 | 0.35 |
| 3905.35 | 0.08 | 0.45 | 3905.80 | 3905.43 | 0.37 |

what I've tried:

- I've checked Pinescript ([https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}vwap](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dvwap))
  but I cannot figure out what's happening within TA.vwap:

```
ta.vwap(source, anchor, stdev_mult) → [series float, series float, series float]
```

- I've used the different Excel formulas for standard deviation: STDEV(), STDEV.S(), and STDEV.P(), all with non-satisfactory results

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Same problem here, even with only 2 data points TV's standard deviation doesn't match. Did you find what was the problem?